# GitHub how to inspect files from the previous commit while preserving the current uncommitted codes?

Tags: git

I know it's a simple question but I don't know how to do it in git.

For example, I have changed lines 10~15 compared to last commit. But now I want to have a look at what the original lines 10~15 look like. So I need to go back to the last commit and be able to come back to my current codes without committing them.

Comment: I guess you could add the current change to a temp branch and later remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) command to save current changes without committing them, and getting back to them later.

From the documentation:

> Stashing takes the dirty state of your working directory — that is,
>   your modified tracked files and staged changes — and saves it on a
>   stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time (even on
>   a different branch)

Below is a sample usage of using stash feature on `master` branch:

1) Say, there are 2 files that were committed in last commit.

```
# Commit message: Adding file1.txt and file2.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

2) Check that there is nothing to commit.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

3) Edit `file1.txt`

```
$ vim file1.txt
```

4) Now, working directory is in a dirty state.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1.txt
```

5) Stash changes

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: e1b8933 Adding file1.txt and file2.txt
HEAD is now at e1b8933 Adding file1.txt and file2.txt
```

6) Look at `file1.txt` as it was committed (i.e. before the local modifications)

```
$ cat file1.txt
```

7) Look at list of stashes

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: e1b8933 Adding file1.txt and file2.txt
```

8) Restore the changes from the stash

```
$ git stash apply
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git diff` to show the differences.

You could use `git show HEAD:foo.txt` to show the file as it was.

Answer (score 0):

You can stash your commit using 
`git stash`

Then you can go to your previous revision by using 
`git checkout [revision]`

To revert back, use `git checkout [branch_name]`

Lets say, your branch is master then, try this to get back
`git checkout master`

To get back your edits, pop your changes using
`git stash pop`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's helpful. I will go to documentation for details about git stash.

Answer (score 0):

1.git stash

```
#-k to keep the index intact, -u to stash the untracked files
git stash push -k -u

#checkout the previous commit xxx
git checkout xxx

#go back to the original commit ooo
git checkout ooo

#apply the stash to restore the uncommitted changes
git stash apply --index
```

2.git worktree

```
#create a worktree and checkout the previous commit xxx's code under /path/foo
git worktree add /path/foo xxx

#the uncommitted changes are still in the current repo

#remove the worktree
git worktree remove /path/foo
```

3.git show

```
#show the content of the previous commit xxx's file bar.txt
git show xxx:bar.txt

#show Lines 10~15
git show xxx:bar.txt | sed -n 10,15p
```

4.git blame

```
#show Line 10-15 of the previous commit xxx's file bar.txt
git blame -s -L 10,15 xxx -- bar.txt
```